# What is the complexity of OSMDroid RadiusMarkerClusterer

Tags: performance, big-o, osmdroid, markerclusterer

I am a bit rusty in big-O calculations and was trying to figure out the complexity of the Osmdroid RadiusMarkerClustering. The java doc says:

```
 Radius-based Clustering algorithm:
 create a cluster using the first point from the cloned list.
 All points that are found within the neighborhood are added to this cluster.
 Then all the neighbors and the main point are removed from the list of points.
 It continues until the list is empty.
```

The cluster algorithm looks like:

```
 private StaticCluster createCluster(Marker m, MapView mapView) {
    GeoPoint clusterPosition = m.getPosition();

    StaticCluster cluster = new StaticCluster(clusterPosition);
    cluster.add(m);

    mClonedMarkers.remove(m);

    if (mapView.getZoomLevel() > mMaxClusteringZoomLevel) {
        //above max level => block clustering:
        return cluster;
    }

    Iterator<Marker> it = mClonedMarkers.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Marker neighbour = it.next();
        int distance = clusterPosition.distanceTo(neighbour.getPosition());
        if (distance <= mRadiusInMeters) {
            cluster.add(neighbour);
            it.remove();
        }
    }

    return cluster;
}
```

Will the big-o be `O(n*(n-m))` where `n` is the amount of points in the cloned list while `m` is the average amount of neighbours?

Comment: Since `m` can be really small, O(n^2) then.